# $-\log\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is convex on an interval between two consecutive roots

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $P(x)=a_nx^n+\dots+a_0$ ($n>1,a_n\neq0$) be a polynomial with real coefficients that has only real roots. Then the function $f(x)=-\log\lvert P(x)\rvert$ is convex on any open interval between two consecutive roots of $P(x)$.

I have tried to use $f''\geq 0$ and induction on $n$ without much success. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By factoring out the roots, we may write $P(x)=\prod_i (x-r_i)$, where we have used the assumption that all roots are real. Then $f(x)=-\sum_i\log(|x-r_i|)$. Since the sum of convex functions is convex, it only remains to check that $-\log(|x-r_i|)$ is convex on any interval not containing one of the roots, which can be done by verifying that the second derivative is positive.

Comment: $P(x)=a_n\prod_i (x-r_i)$, but that does not make a difference